# Elevation у кнопки

Tags: java, android, button

```
Button setDefaultViewOptions(Button button) {  //назначает начальные настройки кнопке и тексту перегружен (2)
    button.setText("New button");
    button.setLayoutParams(viewParams);
    button.setId(buttonsId); //теги и id для массива кнопок
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        button.setElevation(20);
        button.setTranslationZ(10);
        Log.d("TEST","тестирование");
    }
    String buttonTags = "Button:";
    button.setTag(buttonTags + String.valueOf(CountButtonsTags++));
    linearLayout.addView(button);
    buttonsId++;

    return button;
}
```

Есть метод, который назначает стартовые свойства кнопке, одно из этих свойств (высота над layout) elevation. Но высота не увеличивается, а кнопки остается такой же, как была. Почему так происходит? Все остальные свойства работают, метод setElevation() вызывается.

Comment: А на каком устройстве тестируете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стиль кнопки по умолчанию в разделе имеет `StateListAnimator`, который управляет `elevation`. Вы можете удалить существующий аниматор или установить свой собственный, используя `android:stateListAnimator` свойство.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:stateListAnimator="@null" />

<Button
    ...
    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/my_animator" />
```